# C# window form Combobox drop down and sugguest appened list on text written in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combobox which is bind from database and now I want drop down list when I am writing text in combobox and select the data from list which is match with written text in combobox. 
Combobox binding is successfully but on text change in it auto list is not dropdown as per written text. Please suggest me how I can do this.
my binding source is given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Mateenwin
{
public partial class Sale : Form
{
    public Sale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PaymentType_bind();
        Customer_bind();

    }
  /// combobox bind method

  public void PaymentType_bind()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from PaymentType", con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Payment_Type";
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Payment_Type_ID";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox has a property called AutoCompleteMode. It suggests a value which starts with written text. I recommended you that. Also set the AutoCompleteSource to your database.

Comment: DropDownStyle= DropDown

Comment: So you don't want it to complete text. Just a list with appropriate values?